# How to apply MaterialComponents only to some widget?

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-theme, material-components-android

I am migrating from AppCompat to MaterialComponents, and I would like to keep some widgets (like the Bottom Navigation Bar) AppCompat-themed. However, when I want to apply MaterialComponents theming to Buttons and TextFields, I must set my app theme to MaterialComponents.... and therefore all my widgets are MaterialComponents-themed. How can I make only some widgets MaterialComponents-themed ? I have been looking for an answer on StackOverflow but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Most of widgets of material components require a Material Components theme.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use Bridge themes like :

```
Theme.MaterialComponents.Bridge
Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.Bridge
Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar.Bridge
Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar.Bridge
Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar.Bridge
```

Bridge themes inherit from AppCompat themes, but also define the new Material Components theme attributes for you. If you use a bridge theme, you can start using Material Design components without changing your app theme. (From documentaion)

Have a look : [Get started - Material Design](https://material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!